# Forma para bloquear puertos usb y desbloquearlos con clave

Tags: linux

Queria saber si hay una forma de por así decirlo ponerle una autentificacion a los puertos usb , osea si voy a ingresar un usb en tal puerto ,tenga que poner una clave para que me lo reconozca ,algo asi como un login(ya sea consola o interfaz),he visto varias maneras para bloquear puertos , ya sea no cargando el modulo , u eliminando el drive ,pero para este caso , alguien ha hecho algo similar?

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que se podría condicionar el reconocimiento de los dispositivos con reglas de udev que hagan lo que querés pero suena extremadamente hacky
¿Cuál es el caso de uso? Si son dispositivos que se exponen como fichero de bloques (residen en /dev) cambiarles el grupo con reglas de udev parece más lógico que obligar a usar una contraseña para desbloquear las entradas

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/launch-password-prompt-ui-upon-insertion-of-any-usb-device-udev-946409/#post4686812 este es un thread similar en inglés

[https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev_(Español)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev_(Espa%C3%B1ol)) esto de la wiki en español de Arch sobre udev